# Express Server to bypass CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am trying to solve the problem of CORS on the client side. The server side is working fine without any problem but CORS is not enabled. I built a single Page application using React. I am using node Js and express to write a very simple proxy server that will forward all incoming request with path that begins with '/api' to 'https://api.example.com'. I have used request library to achieve this and everything is working fine as expected when tested with postman. But when i try from React frontend; i got this error: `500 Internal Server error`. Please what am i doing wrong? I cant' just wrap my head around this. Your help will be appreciated... Here is the server.js:

```
const express  = require('express');
const path     = require('path');
const request  = require('request');

//create express app instance
const app = express();

//set the port as env variable
const PORT    = process.env.PORT || 3030;
const API_URL = 'https://api.example.com';

//This will pipe the whole request to the API endpoint
//and pipe the response back to the requester.
app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
  req.pipe(request(`${API_URL}${req.url}`)).pipe(res);
});


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Serve any static files
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));
  // Handle React routing, return all requests to React app
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

//The server will now listen on the provided port
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`));
```

Comment: ` 500 Internal Server error`  has nothing to do with CORS.  check the logs of your backend.

Answer (score 1):

Install cors library `npm install cors --save` and use it like so.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

/**use dependencies*/

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I already bye-pass cors with request library. The 500 internal error is so strange because the server side is working correctly.